# sockets & fd sharing: Anything special about sendmsg/recvmsg over msgsnd/msgrcv?

Tags: ipc, file-descriptor, sockets

If I have a tcp server that has a pool of 10 child workers, it seems like I can share a open socket connect with an available child using msgsnd() on the server side and msgrcv() on the worker side instead of using sendmsg() & recvmsg().  Is there something special about sendmsg/recvmsg that I don't know about?

Answer (score 1):

sendmsg() and recvmsg() send/receive data through sockets;  msgsnd() and msgrcv(), on the other hand, send/receive data through message queues.  I don't think they are compatible or related in any way (other than that they both exist on Unix-y systems).

Comment: @Peter Yeah I was wondering if there was some 'magic' that sendmsg/recvmsg does that is different from the ipc msg routines.  My test so far hasn't worked but I was thinking that as long as the receiving programs are children of the server (in the same process group) that it would work.  Still monkeying around with it but at the same time cooking up some a sendmsg/recvmsg trial setup.